# Margin-left make me wrong indentation

Tags: html, css, margin, inline, indentation

I want to know how margin property influence elements I set to display inline.

I know that for inline elements is not possible to use top and bottom margin and with this left-margin, browser makes an indentation on top, not to the left. Small margin is on the bottom too but not on the left side.

Is it possible to make indentation to the left?

```css
/* Reset CSS template , maybe can be here some connection with my problem too */

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* Here I´m including my CSS file */

/* My CSS file */

nav {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p> Autorem článku je Aleš Fišer,kontaktovat ho můžete na této <a href="#adresa">adrese</a></p>
<nav>
  <header role="banner" id="zahlavi">
    <nav role="navigation">
      <ul id="navigácia">
        <li>České Budějovice</li>
        <!-- Here starts my nav -->
        <li>Telč</li>
        <li>Moravské Budějovice</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1>Návštěvníci se pomalu chystají na začátek sezóny</h1>
```

Is it even possible to use nav with `display: inline`? I want to make my nav horizontal, on one row but sadly nothing happens and I don't have bullets here too (maybe some connection with margin). How can I fix it?
This is all for my code

Comment: It seems to be working that way here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_nav.  All links on the same line.  Is this the behavior you want?

Comment: Also, you don't need to comment out text in your posts, just don't make them parts of code (don't indent by 4 spaces).  Not a biggie but it would make it easier to read

Comment: I don't understand why you think you need to make the nav inline anyway, since the only child inside is the ul, a block element. Did you want to make the ul inline instead?

Comment: No,I wanted to make my li elements inline to make my nav horizonatl,but I already fixed it,but thanks for all of your patience and tips guys!!